# User impersonation via admin services in WSO2 possible?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-identity-server

I am making a [RemoteRegistry](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Accessing+Registry+Remotely+through+API) connection to a WSO2 server as user `admin`, but I am in need of being able to create registry resources as a different user (so the owner of the resource is not `admin` but another existing user).  Is it possible to impersonate another user, or obtain a `Registry` instance for another user?

This *is* possible for code that runs inside the WSO2 (for example, code deployed in the built-in Tomcat instance that WSO2 itself runs on), but this particular requirement is for code that accesses the WSO2 server remotely via external APIs, rather than directly from within.

The WSO2 server in question is a WSO2 Identity Server v5.x that also includes functionality from WSO2 Governance Registry.